# How to join table with itself through pivot select where there isn't a relation?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, query-builder

So my `users` table has columns `id` and `fb_id`. The second table `friendships` has two relevant columns `user_id` and `friend_id` which id populated according to `AB` and `BA` principle. When `$user` is signed in I get the array of his friend's `$facebook_ids`.

I can find those users by `$friends = User::whereIn('fb_id', $facebook_ids)`... and then I'm kind of stuck. How do I find users that are according to FB have a friendship, but are not on my friendship table?

EDIT:
By all logic data should be like this [image]
I'm thinking something like

```
$known_friend_query = $session_owner->friends();
$fb_list_query = User::whereIn('fb_id', $fb_ids);
$new_friends = $known_friend_query->join($fb_list_query, 'right outer')->get(); //this line should be wrong
```

But how do I join queries?

Answer (score 0):

The answer as a reminder to self to keep it simple

```
$known_friend_ids = $session_owner->friends()->select('users.id')->get();
$new_friends = User::whereIn('fb_id', $fb_ids)->whereNotIn('id', $known_friend_ids)->get();
```